# NServiceBus - NServiceBus.Persistence.CosmosDB.SagaUpdate.Conflict

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, nservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am facing some issues with the NServiceBus. We are getting the below errors when we process multiple messages. I am using NServiceBus 7.7.0 version.

[image]

Below is the NServiceBus configuration.

```
UseNServiceBus(context =>
            {
                var appInsightsOptions = configuration.GetRequiredSection("AppInsights").Get<AppInsightsOptions>();
                NServiceBus.Logging.ILoggerFactory nservicebusLoggerFactory = new ExtensionsLoggerFactory(loggerFactory: new SerilogLoggerFactory());
                NServiceBus.Logging.LogManager.UseFactory(loggerFactory: nservicebusLoggerFactory);
                var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(endpointName);
                endpointConfiguration.EnableApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration(appInsightsOptions.InstrumentationKey));
                
                var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
                transport.ConnectionString(GetTransportConnectionString(configuration));
                //transport.Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.TransactionScope);
                endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<NewtonsoftSerializer>();
                endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<CosmosPersistence>()
                    .CosmosClient(new CosmosClient(cosmosConnectionString))
                    .DatabaseName(configuration.GetConnectionString("DATABASENAME"))
                    .DefaultContainer(containerName: "sagastore", partitionKeyPath: "/id")
                    .DisableContainerCreation();

                endpointConfiguration.LimitMessageProcessingConcurrencyTo(1);

                endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
                endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
                endpointConfiguration.AuditSagaStateChanges(serviceControlQueue: "audit");
                endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

                return endpointConfiguration;

            }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with NserviceBus but the exception you are receiving is likely resulting from conflicts with optimistic concurrency control, meaning you are trying to make an update on an item that is not the latest version for that document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control  My suggestion is to look at the data you are trying to commit as a batch.

Comment: Optimistic concurrency is the default. You can enable pessimistic concurrency using the instructions [here](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/cosmosdb/saga-concurrency#sagas-concurrency-control-pessimistic-concurrency-control-settings).

Answer (score 2):

By default the `NServiceBus.Persistence.CosmosDB` implementation uses optimistic concurrency control. Depending on the "scatter-gather" nature of the saga optimistic concurrency might not be the best choice because it can lead to the effects you are seeing. When multiple messages try to update the same saga instance at the same time, one update wins and all others will have to roll back and retry. The saga concurrency behavior is explained in more details in the [saga concurrency](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/concurrency) documentation with [specific guidance for CosmosDB](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/cosmosdb/saga-concurrency).

You can switch from optimistic concurrency to pessimistic concurrency by [overriding the locking mode](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/cosmosdb/saga-concurrency#sagas-concurrency-control)

```cs
var sagaPersistenceConfiguration = persistence.Sagas();
sagaPersistenceConfiguration.UsePessimisticLocking();
```

This is an endpoint level switch and pessimistic concurrency comes with its own sets of tradeoffs as [explained in the internals section](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/cosmosdb/saga-concurrency#sagas-concurrency-control-pessimistic-locking-internals) of the documentation. You can either globally switch the mode for the endpoint that saga is running, or think about isolating this specific saga out into its own dedicated endpoint.

Comment: I have added this pessimistic locking code but I see the same issue.

Comment: @RajuDonthula would you mind [contacting us via the non-critical support](https://particular.net/support) so that we can take a more in-depth look into what is going on there?